# How to Get The Out-Of-Set Percentile In PostgreSQL?

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, scipy, percentile

Given a tables

```
product1_id | score
A  |   2 
B  |   3
```

and

```
product2_id | score
W  |   1
X  |   2
Y  |   3
Z  |   4
```

how can I find the out-of-set percentiles of product1 scores among product2 scores using PostgreSQL to get an expected output of:

```
product1_id | score | out_of_set_percentile
A  |   2  |  50
B  |   3  |  75.
```

In python one way to solve this would be to merge the tables and apply `scipy.percentileofscore`:

```
from scipy import stats
stats.percentileofscore([1, 2, 3, 4], 3)  # 75.0,
```

but I'd like a way to do this natively in PostgreSQL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a brute force method:

```
select t1.product_id, t1.score,
       avg( (t2.score <= t1.score)::int ) as ratio
from t1 cross join
     t2
group by t1.product_id, t1.score;
```